# now my blog link says 'forbidden'

Tags: wordpress

My site http://www.landlordslawyer.co.uk/ on 4.0.1 . It has a link http://www.landlordslawyer.co.uk/blog that worked fine.

Only now the link to the blog is giving me 
`Forbidden
You don't have permission to access /blog/ on this server.`

which I don't understand because everything else is fine.

What can I do please?

Comment: did you modify something on the server? apache-config?

Comment: The only thing we did was set a woocommerce gateway to lve. Nothing more.  So I don't think so

Comment: woocommerce is a plugin to your wordpress blog? did you make a backup before?

Comment: But it was installed ages ago - and the blog has been working fine. I will go back and deactivate it though, see if that makes a difference

Comment: darn - now my whole site has gone - http 500 internal errors (and I didn't deactivate anything). I think its time to contact the host.